# Error while loading data in Angularjs datatable fetched after server side

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to implement data server side paging using angularjs datatable and rest api calls. The problem im facing is when I click on the next button on the pagination, the data being sent from the server is not getting loaded in the datatble after successful callback. It shows message "processing.." and hence gets stuck. Here is my controller code.

```
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
.withOption('ajax', {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': $rootScope.currentUser.authToken
    },
    error : function (xhr,status,error)
    { 
        if(status === 401){
            window.location.replace("/pc-web/userHome");
            errorFlash(error);
        }
    },
    url: GET_ROOMLIST,
    type: 'GET'
})
// or here
.withDataProp(function(json) {
      console.log(json);

      return json.data;
    })
.withOption('processing', true)
.withOption('serverSide', true)
.withDOM('frtip')
.withDisplayLength(9)
    .withOption('createdRow', function (row) {
        // Recompiling so we can bind Angular directive to the DT
        $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
    })
    .withOption('saveState', true)
    .withOption('order', [0, 'asc'])
  .withPaginationType('simple_numbers')
.withButtons([
            {
                extend:    'csvHtml5',
                text:      'Export',
                titleAttr: 'CSV',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
                }
            }])

    .withOption('initComplete', function(settings) {
        // Recompiling so we can bind Angular directive to the DT
        $compile(angular.element('#' + settings.sTableId).contents())($scope);

    })
    ;
```

The data being returned from the server is in the format :

```
data:(9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

draw:1

message:null

recordsFiltered:100

recordsTotal:100

success:true
```

Im using datatable version :
 * angular-datatables - v0.5.6
 * https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables

angular js version : 1.5.6

Comment: anyone got solution to this?